# Dataflow Flex Template max size allowed

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

Hi I trying to find the max size allowed for the dataflow run in flex mode and a way to check the size.
I know the classic template has a limit of 10MB per template.

But Searching on the Google Cloud documentation I was not able to find if the size is the same as the classic one.

On the classic template I can check the size of my template by checking the file size inside a bucket.

But for the flex template I can't do that because the flex templates runs as a Container file so
its build when the job is running.
One thing I can do is check the Uber jar that my java project package before upload to GCP.

But I'm assuming the template is the max size of the graph that dataflow generate and not by the size of the application (my jars has around 90 ~ 120MB and runs fine in the GCP).

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no size limit for `Dataflow Flex Template`.

Too big fat jar can reduce the runtime, but as far as I know there is no quota or limit for Flex template.